# which ANTLR4 output language runs fastest?

Tags: antlr4

Has anyone compared the speed differences in output language for an ANTLR4 project? They support C#, Java, Python2 and Python3. If you don't care much about the output language, which one would you recommend and why?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't compared them myself, but it's very likely that you see the same differences like for any other code in the different languages. Why should that be different for the generated parser code? So I expect C# being the fastest here, followed by Java and then Python. The C++ target is under work currently, which I expect to be on par or even faster than C#. Still, I'm speculating here, even though it's an educated guess.

Hence, if the language doesn't matter I would obviously choose C# then, or, if you can wait a bit more, the C++ target (which is much more portable, if that is relevant for you).